# PHPExcel doesnt download xls

Tags: php, phpexcel

Saw many similar questions but nothing helped. I use PHPExcel.
I tried

```
$filename = "report.xls";
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename);
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($pExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save("php://output");
```

and this

```
$filename = "report.xlsx";
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($pExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save("php://output");
```

But it shows in browser "PKoCjKG�D�X�[Content_Types].xml��MN�0���"" like this and doesnt force to download.

Comment: your "Content-Type:" headers simply overwrite each other

Comment: i used each other but same result.

Comment: Replace first line with `header("Content-Type:   application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");` try

Comment: nothing changed

Comment: maybe need something in htaccess? but i dont know what

Comment: please add a reproducable test case (=code that can be run). We cannot know what are your `$pExcel` or `filename`.

Comment: Is this an Ajax request for download?

Comment: Set file encoding "UTF-8 without BOM" instead my "UTF8" and it works

Answer (score 0):

change filename to $filename, if you determine it before.
Example:

```
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename);
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"");` but same result

Comment: maybe need something in htaccess? but i dont know what

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me.

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=output.xls");
```

Comment: I publish this code to my server you can test it. http://kongarn.com/script/excel.php

Comment: maybe need write something in htaccess file? Because in my case it doesnt work

Comment: Please test only this code on your server. I mean you must remove this line first $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');

Comment: I dont know what it means. But I opened my php file in np++ and set file encoding  "UTF-8 without BOM" instead my "UTF8" and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Replace

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
```

With

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
```

I faced similar (Not exact) issue and fixed it from above mentioned code, Also I used it [Here](https://github.com/KundanGaira/Cakephp-phpexcel-component/blob/master/cakephp2/PhpExcelComponent.php) .

Comment: its types for different formats. I used both. But same trouble.